# Why can't I purchase coins in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I can't seem to buy any Poke Coins on my iPhone app. Has anyone else had this issue and how did you resolve it?

I usually go to the Shop and press on the coins that I want to purchase but it does nothing and we therefore can't buy any items in the shop.

Comment: Have you tried killing the app and trying again? 
Sometimes I've had various apps bug out on me when doing in app purchasing and the "Confirm Purchase" box never seems to appear. Killing the app and retrying tends to solve for me.

Comment: Did you by chance deactivate inapp purchases via your provider? I know you can with some providers and it doesn´t always produce messages.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing happens when you tap on the coins in the shop, you probably have in-app purchases disabled on your phone, possibly through parental controls.